# Obstacle avoidance via steering behaviour when near gaps

Tags: c++, ai, path-finding, steering-behaviors

I'm trying to implement RTS-like character control on C++/SDL2 for a character with a rectangular hitbox. I have a path-finding algorithm ready and I want to implement obstacle avoidance steering behaviour. My current implementation uses the distances from the corners of colliders to the center of the character's collider and calculates the vector sum, here's the code:

```
//SteeringHandler.h
#ifndef STEERING_HANDLER_H_
#define STEERING_HANDLER_H_

#include "Vector2.h"
#include <vector>
#include <array>

class SteeringHandler
{
public:
    SteeringHandler(float colliderPointRangeLimit_);
    void reset(const Vector2<float> &pos_);
    void addColliderPoint(const Vector2<float> point_);
    Vector2<float> getDirection();

private:
    Vector2<float> m_ownPos;
    float m_colliderPointRangeLimit;
    Vector2<float> m_steeringDir;

};

#endif

//SteeringHandler.cpp
#include "SteeringHandler.h"

SteeringHandler::SteeringHandler(float colliderPointRangeLimit_) :
    m_colliderPointRangeLimit(colliderPointRangeLimit_)
{
}

void SteeringHandler::reset(const Vector2<float> &pos_)
{
    m_ownPos = pos_;
    m_steeringDir = {0, 0};
}

void SteeringHandler::addColliderPoint(const Vector2<float> point_)
{
    auto dirToSelf = m_ownPos - point_;
    auto len = dirToSelf.getLen();
    if (len > m_colliderPointRangeLimit)
        return;

    auto value = m_colliderPointRangeLimit - len;
    m_steeringDir += dirToSelf.normalised() * value;
}

Vector2<float> SteeringHandler::getDirection()
{
    return m_steeringDir;
}
```

However, it causes weird behaviour while moving through or near gaps:

[image]

The blue rectangles are the points of the path, the blue line is the vector returned by `SteeringHandler`.

If I increase the `m_colliderPointRangeLimit` value or multiply the returned "avoidance" vector, the character stops passing through the gap. How can I improve my algorithm and fix this issue?

EDIT: I've tried to implement something closer to context steering. I'm comparing the player's collider to the borders of static colliders - if the player is near the border, the vectors towards this border are considered as danger, and if the player is behind the border (for example, in the example above player was behind lower border), the vectors along the normal from this wall are considered as interest. But it's too hard-coded, it doesn't work well though the specific situations vary depending on `m_colliderPointRangeLimit` and `valueMultiplier` and it probably will work even worse when I add other units.

```
//SteeringHandler.h
#ifndef STEERING_HANDLER_H_
#define STEERING_HANDLER_H_

#include "Vector2.h"
#include <vector>
#include <array>

class SteeringHandler
{
public:
    SteeringHandler(float colliderPointRangeLimit_, const Collider &playerCollider_);
    void reset(const Vector2<float> &pos_);
    void addCollider(const Collider &collider_);
    void addDesiredDirection(const Vector2<float> dir_);
    Vector2<float> getDirection();

private:
    void addInterestDir(const Vector2<float> &v_);
    void addDangerDir(const Vector2<float> &v_);
    float dirToVerticalLine(const Vector2<float> &p1, const Vector2<float> &p2);
    float dirTohorizontalLine(const Vector2<float> &p1, const Vector2<float> &p2);

    Collider m_playerCollider;
    Vector2<float> m_ownPos;
    float m_colliderPointRangeLimit;

    std::array<Vector2<float>, 8> m_steerDirs = {
        directions::Up(),
        directions::UpRight(),
        directions::Right(),
        directions::DownRight(),
        directions::Down(),
        directions::DownLeft(),
        directions::Left(),
        directions::UpLeft()
    };

    std::array<float, 8> m_interests;
    std::array<float, 8> m_dangers;
};

#endif

//SteeringHandler.cpp
#include "SteeringHandler.h"

SteeringHandler::SteeringHandler(float colliderPointRangeLimit_, const Collider &playerCollider_) :
    m_colliderPointRangeLimit(colliderPointRangeLimit_),
    m_playerCollider(playerCollider_)
{
}

void SteeringHandler::reset(const Vector2<float> &pos_)
{
    m_ownPos = pos_;
    m_interests.fill(0);
    m_dangers.fill(0);
}

void SteeringHandler::addCollider(const Collider &collider_)
{
    const float valueMultiplier = 0.7f;

    auto playerCollider = m_playerCollider + m_ownPos;

    Vector2<float> p1 = {collider_.x, collider_.y};
    Vector2<float> p2 = {collider_.x, collider_.y + collider_.h};
    float dirToLine = dirToVerticalLine(p1, p2);
    if (dirToLine < m_colliderPointRangeLimit)
    {
        float value = 1.0f - dirToLine / m_colliderPointRangeLimit;
        value *= valueMultiplier;

        if (playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w <= p1.x)
            addDangerDir({value * 0.95f, 0.0f});
        else
            addInterestDir({-value, 0.0f});
    }

    p1 = {collider_.x + collider_.w, collider_.y};
    p2 = {collider_.x + collider_.w, collider_.y + collider_.h};
    dirToLine = dirToVerticalLine(p1, p2);
    if (dirToLine < m_colliderPointRangeLimit)
    {
        float value = 1.0f - dirToLine / m_colliderPointRangeLimit;
        value *= valueMultiplier;


        if (playerCollider.x >= p1.x)
            addDangerDir({-value * 0.95f, 0.0f});
        else
            addInterestDir({value, 0.0f});
    }

    p1 = {collider_.x, collider_.y};
    p2 = {collider_.x + collider_.w, collider_.y};
    dirToLine = dirTohorizontalLine(p1, p2);
    if (dirToLine < m_colliderPointRangeLimit)
    {
        float value = 1.0f - dirToLine / m_colliderPointRangeLimit;
        value *= valueMultiplier;

        if (playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h <= p1.y)
            addDangerDir({0.0f, value * 0.95f});
        else
            addInterestDir({0.0f, -value});
    }

    p1 = {collider_.x, collider_.y + collider_.h};
    p2 = {collider_.x + collider_.w, collider_.y + collider_.h};
    dirToLine = dirTohorizontalLine(p1, p2);
    if (dirToLine < m_colliderPointRangeLimit)
    {
        float value = 1.0f - dirToLine / m_colliderPointRangeLimit;
        value *= valueMultiplier;

        if (playerCollider.y >= p1.y)
            addDangerDir({0.0f, -value * 0.95f});
        else
            addInterestDir({0.0f, value});
    }
}

void SteeringHandler::addDesiredDirection(const Vector2<float> dir_)
{
    addInterestDir(dir_);
}

Vector2<float> SteeringHandler::getDirection()
{
    Vector2<float> sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_steerDirs.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto added = m_interests[i] - m_dangers[i];
        if (added > 0)
            sum += m_steerDirs[i] * added;
    }

    return sum.normalised();
}

void SteeringHandler::addInterestDir(const Vector2<float> &v_)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_steerDirs.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto val = utils::projectionLen(v_, m_steerDirs[i]);
        if (val > m_interests[i])
            m_interests[i] = val;
    }
}

void SteeringHandler::addDangerDir(const Vector2<float> &v_)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_steerDirs.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto val = utils::projectionLen(v_, m_steerDirs[i]);
        if (val > m_dangers[i])
            m_dangers[i] = val;
    }
}

float SteeringHandler::dirToVerticalLine(const Vector2<float> &p1, const Vector2<float> &p2)
{
    auto playerCollider = m_playerCollider + m_ownPos;

    //if (playerCollider.y <= p1.y && playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h >= p2.y)
    if (playerCollider.y <= p1.y && playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h >= p1.y ||
        playerCollider.y <= p2.y && playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h >= p2.y ||
        playerCollider.y >= p1.y && playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h <= p2.y)
    {
        return std::min(abs(playerCollider.x - p1.x), abs(playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w - p1.x));
    }

    if (playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w < p1.x)
        return std::min((p1 - Vector2{playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w, playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h}).getLen(),
                        (p2 - Vector2{playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w, playerCollider.y}).getLen());
    else if (playerCollider.x > p1.x)
        return std::min((p1 - Vector2{playerCollider.x, playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h}).getLen(),
                        (p2 - Vector2{playerCollider.x, playerCollider.y}).getLen());
    else
        return std::min(abs(playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h - p1.y), abs(playerCollider.y - p2.y));

}

float SteeringHandler::dirTohorizontalLine(const Vector2<float> &p1, const Vector2<float> &p2)
{
    auto playerCollider = m_playerCollider + m_ownPos;

    if (playerCollider.x <= p1.x && playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w >= p1.x ||
        playerCollider.x <= p2.x && playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w >= p2.x ||
        playerCollider.x >= p1.x && playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w <= p2.x)
    {
        return std::min(abs(playerCollider.y - p1.y), abs(playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h - p1.y));
    }

    return std::min((p1 - Vector2{playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w, playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h / 2}).getLen(),
                    (p2 - Vector2{playerCollider.x, playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h / 2}).getLen());

    if (playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h < p1.y)
        return std::min((p1 - Vector2{playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w, playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h}).getLen(),
                        (p2 - Vector2{playerCollider.x, playerCollider.y + playerCollider.h}).getLen());
    else if (playerCollider.y > p1.y)
        return std::min((p1 - Vector2{playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w, playerCollider.y}).getLen(),
                        (p2 - Vector2{playerCollider.x, playerCollider.y}).getLen());
    else
        return std::min(abs(playerCollider.x + playerCollider.w - p1.x), abs(playerCollider.x - p2.x));
}
```

EDIT 2: I tried to use collider corners with a context steering system and it seems to work fine with the doubled weight of colliders for one character, but it causes characters to be struck in the wall when they get pushed away by, for example, other characters:

[image]

One question that I have at this point is: Do RTS games actually use colliders to prevent the characters from going through walls or do they only rely on pathfinding and steering algorithms?